# get checkbox data-ids as they are checked -> push vals to array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I am trying to continuously update an array with checked checkbox `data-id` *values* as the check-boxes become checked (to trigger I added a click event listener on parent elem to re-check all states). I currently have the below, which somewhat works, but for some reasons pushes duplicate `values` into the array.

```
function getCur(event) {
        let chkst = document.querySelector('.parent');
        if (chkst) { 
            chkst.addEventListener("click", checkWtc);
        } else {
          getCur();
        }
      }
    
     function checkWtc(event) { 
           let chkstats = document.querySelectorAll('input.mychex[type=checkbox]:checked');
           if (chkstats) { 
              for (let i = 0; i < chkstats.length; i++) {
                chIds.push(chkstats[i].getAttribute("data-id"));
                console.log(chIds);
                alert(chIds); 
              };
           } else {
             checkWtc();
           }
      }
```

*i.e.* in the alert below, I get consistent duplicate ids from the previous checked `data-id` before the new is updated to the array:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think would do something like this (adding a single listener to the parent)

```js
//  array holding checked id's
const checked = [];

//  add eventlistener listener on parent (listen for change event)
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('change', e => {

  //  get checkbox id
  const id = e.target.id;
  //  if you need it as data-id just change the above to
  //  const id = e.target.dataset.id;


  //  if the target is checked add the id to the array  
  if (e.target.checked) checked.push(id);

  //  if not – remove it 
  else checked.splice(checked.indexOf(id), 1);

  //  this just displays the checked id's  
  log.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(checked)
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="foo" />Foo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="bar" />Bar</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="baz" />Baz</label>
</div>
<pre id="log"><!-- show checked id's --></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't supply the html i added some.

1. apply the listener directly to the checkbox elements
2. when its called just grab the elements with the data-id attr that are checked since those are all you care about
3. change the html collection into an array and then map the array to extract the data-id of each element.

```js
(function addDataIdListeners() {
  const els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'));
  els.forEach(function (el) { el.addEventListener('change', checkWtc); });
})();

 function checkWtc(event) { 
     const chkstats = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id]:checked'));
     let arr = chkstats.map(function (c) { return c.getAttribute('data-id'); });
     console.log(arr); //return arr here if needed or further manipulate it
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-id="0">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="1">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="2">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="3">
<input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
```